# Line following robot mathematic model

Tags: pid, matlab, line-following

I'm trying to improve the speed my line following robot. I have made this chassis designs. This is the main prototype I'm working on. Look at the following image.[image]

I'm driving the robot with PID, and with previous robots, I noticed it's quite hard to tune these constants perfectly so I'm trying use MATLAB to tune it.

Is there an equation or function that can describe the motion of the robot provided all the dimensions are known so that I can simulate it in MATLAB?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: One option is to use the STRIPS language for creating a behavior model. In the 1970s the same was done in the Shakey the robot project. Then a planner can use the behavior model to bring the robot into the goal state.

Comment: I haven't heard of this before, but it seems to be more complex than deriving from first principle

Comment: There are like equations to figure out the [cycle time for a line follower](https://www.academia.edu/26976177/Design_and_Methodology_of_Line_Follower_Automated_Guided_Vehicle-A_Review).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The robot you're trying to model is known as a *Two Wheeled Differential Robot*. It's easy to find specific kinematic models for it. You can start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE7RQNhwnPQ) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbjaAMM5ZF4).